# VB.NET - DateValue("0:0:0")

Tags: vb.net

Please see the variable declaration below:

```
dim DateTest As Date = DateValue("0:0:0")
```

What is DateTest actually initialised with.  If I step through the code, then it says: #12:00:00 AM#.  If I try to enter this into the database (datetime field) then an SQLTypeException is thrown, which says: "SqlDateTime overflow. Must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM."

Does DateValue("0:0:0") initialise the date variable with a date value?

Comment: Why not step through the code and tell us what DateTest.Year is? Does it lie between the SQL bounds?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Obviously it returns [`Date.MinValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.minvalue.aspx) which is the smallest possible value of `Date`. The value of this constant is equivalent to 00:00:00.0000000, January 1, 0001. Since the year 0001 is smaller than 1753, the database throws the exception.

I didn't know `DateValue`, but instead of old VB functions i would use .NET methods like [`Date.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k1skd40.aspx).  For example:

```
Dim DateTest As Date = Date.Parse("2008-05-01")
```

Answer (score 2):

Ah, the min of a datetime field in .net is much smaller than the min date of a datetime field in Sql Server. If you would like to store a value that matches, I suggest using the DateTime2(7) datatype in sql server.

Please see the following articles about min date times:

tsql min datetime
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx

.net min datetime
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.minvalue.aspx

tsql datetime2 description:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677335.aspx